# Issue creating an array of objects from a csv file

Tags: arrays, list, object, hashtable, powershell-3.0

I'm fairly new with Powershell, so this is likely a rookie mistake, but I am trying to take a CSV document containing only user display names, query AD for the required information, and populate that information into object properties using a hash table.

Here is what i have right now

```
$Path = "C:\Scripts\Generate-CSRSpreadsheets\Roster-Jpay.csv"
$Table = Import-csv -Path $Path -Header EmployeeDisplayName
$Array = @()
$ADUser = Get-ADUser -Properties DisplayName,Manager -Filter {DisplayName -eq $_.EmployeeDisplayname}


ForEach($User in $Table){

    $Object = New-Object PSObject -Property @{

        DisplayName = $ADUser.DisplayName
        GivenName   = $ADUser.GivenName
        Surname     = $ADUser.Surname
        Email       = $ADUser.Mail
    }

    $Array += $Object
}
```

This seems to me like it should work fine, but when I check my output it looks something like this:

[Example Output Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/51rWt.png)

Let's say in this example I have 9 total users, but it's only outputting the information from the last user in the csv. I've been pouring over this code, but I can't see what's wrong with it. Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to move your `Get-ADUser` inside the loop:

```
$Path = "C:\Scripts\Generate-CSRSpreadsheets\Roster-Jpay.csv"
$Table = Import-csv -Path $Path -Header EmployeeDisplayName
$Array = @()

ForEach($User in $Table){

    $ADUser = Get-ADUser -Filter "DisplayName -eq '$($User.EmployeeDisplayName)'" -Properties DisplayName,Manager

    $Object = New-Object PSObject -Property @{

        DisplayName = $ADUser.DisplayName
        GivenName   = $ADUser.GivenName
        Surname     = $ADUser.Surname
        Email       = $ADUser.Mail
    }

    $Array += $Object
}
```

Comment: That worked! Thank you. I'm not sure logically why that works and the other way does not, but thanks for the help!